# GetMaterialApp added, showing error on showErrorSnackBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have already added my `GetMaterialApp` in my `main.dart` but I am getting error in my `common.dart`. The error is `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`  in line 3. The `heading` has `null` value and in `error!` is showing:

```
"You are trying to use contextless navigation without
      a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
      If you are testing your app, you can use:
      [Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
      a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
      for a [GetMaterialApp].
      "
```

> common.dart

```
  static void showErrorSnackBar(String? error,
      {bool instantInit = true, String? heading}) {
    Get.snackbar(heading ?? "Error", error!, // line 3
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        instantInit: instantInit,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10));
  }
```

In my `main.dart`, I have used `flutter_background_services` to fetch updates on current location every 15 minutes. This is how I do it.

```
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  // Only available for flutter 3.0.0 and later
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 15), (timer) async {
    await control();
    print("executed at line 180");
    service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
      service.stopSelf();
      if (timer.isActive) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  });
  print('Flutter Background Service : ${DateTime.now()}');
}
```

In my `control()` is where I ping my location.

```
control() async {
  await lC.pingLocation(); //get current location
}
```

In my `pingLocation()`, this is where I get my location. It pings every 15 seconds to check if the user is within 2km. If it is, then it pings and do nothing. If it pings the next 15 seconds, and checks that user is not within 2km, then I need to display `showErrorSnackBar` which I have displayed in my `common.dart`. So I included `try{} catch{e}` to show the error if the user is out of range (not within 2km). So I changed the simulator location to somewhere far away 2km, and the `catch(e)` is caught. It executed   `Utils.showErrorSnackBar(e.toString());` and this is how I got the error `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)` which I suspect that is the cause of `You are trying to use contextless navigation without a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.`

> my pingLocation()

```
  pingLocation() async {
    // var isRunning = await service.isRunning();
    try {
      await _getCurrentPosition();
      print('is called');
      print(DateTime.now().toString());
      if (response.success! && response.fullResponse != null) {
        final responseData = response.fullResponse.data;
        if (responseData != null && responseData != 0) {
if(responseData.toString() == "[]"){
Get.offAllNamed(AppRoutes.home); //Cause of the error as well!
}
          }
    } catch (e) {
      Utils.showErrorSnackBar(e.toString()); //error
    }
  }
```

Another side note, when I don't use pingLocation() in main.dart, error doesn't occur. Any suggestions?

> Those who wants to see my `main.dart` with `GetMaterialApp`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en', 'IN'),
        Locale('en', 'US'),
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      getPages: AppPages.all,
      initialRoute: PrefData().readString('isLogin') == 'true'
          ? AppRoutes.home
          : AppRoutes.login,
      enableLog: true,
      navigatorKey: Get.key,
      locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
    );
  }
```

Update!

`Get.offAllNamed(AppRoutes.home)` is the cause of the error as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see. Seems like I should go for Provider for my next project. I am on Discord and just joined Flutter server. Much appreciated!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz actually, could I please have your opinion on which state management would you use? Bloc, Provider or Riverpod for Android and iOS?

Comment: Provider is in maintenance mode.  Even the author recommends new projects start with RiverPod.  However if you want the rigor of Bloc, we won't object.

Comment: Noted. I am currently watching your videos, your take on Riverpod! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Replce your `MaterialApp` with `GetMaterialApp`. Something like this.

```
GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
          home: HomePage(),
        )
```

**Instead**

```
MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
          title: 'Gst invoice and billing',
          home: HomePage(),
        )
```

Comment: In `main.dart`?

Comment: yes, you will find there `MaterialApp` Replace by the `GetMaterialApp`

Comment: I added `GetMaterialApp` in `main.dart` but still same. I updated my post which explains how I got the error.